# Tab Rich Control: Underline functionality is not working

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

Tab Rich control page is displaying the underline when the user selects and click on 'U' button. But it is not saving the HTML tag for the underline and hence it is not showing the underline when it come back from database..

Comment: You may need to use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txt.Text)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode the _underline_-html and store that in dbms.

Comment: You need to show us the code where you insert/update the record. Otherwise we cannot say what you must change.

Comment: This is my xmal code used to bind my Tab rich control to database : 
<local:TabbedRichTextBox x:Name="descShort" HtmlText="{Binding description_short, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,5" BorderThickness="0" />

Comment: Is this Silverlight or WPF? You should tag it accordingly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We need to apply some HTMLExportSettings of HTML Format Provider, so it can generate HTML tag for underline. In order to achieve best compatibility of the generated HTML with Telerik Reporting, you should apply the following settings:

```
DocumentExportLevel - Fragment;
StylesExportMode - Inline;
StyleRepositoryExportMode - DontExportStyles;
ExportFontStylesAsTags - true.
```

You can also read complete options of HTML export settings of HTML format provider for generating right HTML..follow the following link ::
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radrichtextbox-features-import-export-settings.html